# enable / disable scaling on Azure VMSS with powershell

Tags: azure-powershell

Is there a way to enable or disable scaling for an Azure VMSS without providing all the rules and profiles to Add-AzureRmAutoscaleSetting

Comment: can you elaborate a bit?

Comment: I have created a scaling setting as per example 1 on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.insights/add-azurermautoscalesetting?view=azurermps-5.1.1. There are times that we need to disable the scaling via powershell, then later on enable it again

Answer (score 1):

According to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.insights/add-azurermautoscalesetting?view=azurermps-5.1.1#optional-parameters) there is the `-DisableSetting` switch which you can use to achieve what you want

Comment: I have tried using that and it only seems to work if im passing in the profile, and that means I need to also pass in the rules to the profile. So it would appear the only way to use this is to declare all of the rules again. At one point I thought well I can get all the rules that are currently in place by running Get-AzureRmAutoscaleSetting with -DetailedOutput to then build up in powershell what the current rules are to pass through to this, but Get-AzureRmAutoscaleSetting with -DetailedOutput isnt actually giving me detailed output

Comment: well, i havent tried that, but looking at the output of [this example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.insights/get-azurermautoscalesetting?view=azurermps-5.1.1) it looks like `-detailedoutput` does what you need

Comment: I know it says on there that -detailedoutput gives a detailed output, but it isnt for me, I think it has been removed but document not updated.

Comment: I have now been able to do it by using the following:  $myResourceGroup = 'my_rsg'
$myLocation = 'West Europe'
$myScaleName = 'scalename'

$scale = Get-AzureRmAutoscaleSetting -ResourceGroupName $myResourceGroup -Name $myScaleName

Add-AzureRmAutoscaleSetting -AutoscaleProfile $scale.Profiles `
                             -Location $myLocation `
                             -Name $scale.Name `
                             -ResourceGroupName $myResourceGroup `
                             -TargetResourceId $scale.TargetResourceUri `
                             -DisableSetting

Answer (score 0):

Done it using the following powershell:

```
$myResourceGroup = 'my_rsg'
$myLocation = 'West Europe'
$myScaleName = 'scalename'

$scale = Get-AzureRmAutoscaleSetting -ResourceGroupName $myResourceGroup -Name $myScaleName

Add-AzureRmAutoscaleSetting -AutoscaleProfile $scale.Profiles `
                             -Location $myLocation `
                             -Name $scale.Name `
                             -ResourceGroupName $myResourceGroup `
                             -TargetResourceId $scale.TargetResourceUri `
                             -DisableSetting
```